# Control added in RichtextBox in c#, but can not scroll along with other text

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am using a RichTextbox in my program to show multiple line strings in c sharp. I also need to add clickable control like button, label etc. I can add the control inside the RichTextBox properly by the following url below:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/33dd0de0-1e30-4f68-a3e2-7b4b2f2170af/

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "123";
b.Size = new Size(30, 30);
b.Location = new Point(50, 50);
b.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.richTextBox1.Text += "123";
};
this.richTextBox1.Controls.Add(b);
```

But when I scroll the RichTextBox the controls do not move accordingly along with the text. Is there any way to move the controls as well with the text?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. All you're doing with this code is adding a control into the RTB which acts as a container. It isn't part of the RTF document underneath.

You can draw buttons in there.. via the use of some Shape-Drawing RTF. [I will point you to the RTF Specification on how to do that.](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)

However, as for wiring up a click event to those RTF buttons.. I have no idea unfortunately.

(PS, you might be better off going with WPF's `FlowDocument` for this, which should do what you're after, but requires a bit more learning)